# Neural networks assume continuity, what does this mean?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, conv-neural-network, convolution

I encountered the following paragraph by Pedro Domingos (mentioned in Gary F. Marcus paper):

> ANNs assume continuity, graphical models assume conditional
>   independence, and instance-based learning assumes similarity; and
>   correspondingly, neural nets make it easy to incorporate types of
>   continuity like translation invariance, graphical models [make it easy
>   to incorporate] conditional independences, and [instance-based models
>   make it easy to incorporate] knowledge of what makes things similar
>   (in the kernel or distance measure, which will vary with the domain).

I understand conceptually what is translation invariance, but I don't understand what is meant by continuity and why translation invariance is a kind of continuity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A continuous function is (very informally), one you can draw/plot on a graph without lifting your pen. See [this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function) for the gory details.

If you implement a translation function: $x' = \text{translate}(x, \Delta)$ which takes image $x$ and translation amount $\Delta$, using bilinear interpolation, then it will be continuous wrt both $x$ and $\Delta$. Let $f(\cdot)$ be a continuous neural network. Then $g(x,\Delta) = f(\text{translate}(x, \Delta))$ is continuous wrt both $x$ and $\Delta$ since continuity is closed under composition.

This is all to say that since neural networks are continuous with respect to the input *image*, they will also be continuous with respect to the amount of *translation*, which of course is a prerequisite for being translation invariant (keep in mind neural networks aren't really translation invariant in the formal sense).

Anyway I think the connection between continuity and translation invariance is quite shaky in the paragraph you quoted... I wouldn't read into it too much.